# Overflow-y inside tbody for whole rows

Tags: html, css, overflow, bootstrap-5

I have a problem with using overflow-y inside tbody. I want to set the maximum height of the tbody but after applying the overflow-y, my tbody shrank into 1 column as seen as in image 1. Can someone help me to fix the problem? Thank you

Here is the HTML code:

```css
.item-list .item-detail{
    margin: 0 0 2px 4px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

.table > :not(caption) > * > * {
    padding: 0.3rem 0.3rem !important;
    background-color: var(--vz-table-bg);
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9999px var(--vz-table-accent-bg);
}
.color-display{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
.text-center {
    text-align: center !important;
}

/* The codes i added*/

.tbody-responsive{
    display: block;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="item-list py-4">
  <div class="item-header">

  </div>
  <div class="item-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <table class="table">
          <thead class="">
            <th>
              <h4><b>DETAIL</b></h4>
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              <h4><b>STOCK (Client)</b></h4>
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              <h4><b>STOCK (XXX)</b></h4>
            </th>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="tbody-responsive w-100">

            <tr>
              <td class="item-detail"> Polo SE, Red <span class="color-display" style="background-color: red"></span>, XL</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
            </tr>
            
             <tr>
              <td class="item-detail"> Polo SE, Red <span class="color-display" style="background-color: red"></span>, XL</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
            </tr>
            
             <tr>
              <td class="item-detail"> Polo SE, Red <span class="color-display" style="background-color: red"></span>, XL</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
            </tr>
            
             <tr>
              <td class="item-detail"> Polo SE, Red <span class="color-display" style="background-color: red"></span>, XL</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
            </tr>
            
             <tr>
              <td class="item-detail"> Polo SE, Red <span class="color-display" style="background-color: red"></span>, XL</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
            </tr>
            
             <tr>
              <td class="item-detail"> Polo SE, Red <span class="color-display" style="background-color: red"></span>, XL</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
            </tr>
            
             <tr>
              <td class="item-detail"> Polo SE, Red <span class="color-display" style="background-color: red"></span>, XL</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
            </tr>
            
             <tr>
              <td class="item-detail"> Polo SE, Red <span class="color-display" style="background-color: red"></span>, XL</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The result of the code

[image]

I want to make the width into like this. I have tried using `width:100%` or w-100 in class but neither work.

The expected width

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you for your feedback on helping me. I am new with the tools in Creating Question. So sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: I have updated the code with bootstrap cdn. It looks more similar to the original problem as seen in screenshot.

Comment: You put `display: block` on the tbody element, thereby robbing it of all properties that come with the `table-row-group` display type it would originally have. (Yes, I am aware, if you remove it, the height limitation won't work any more. But with it, the whole table layout collapses to begin with.)

Comment: What can i do to make it intented as i meant to be? i have tried adding a div and giving the div the `tbody-responsive` class and yes it doesnt work

Comment: You can not insert div elements in arbitrary positions between table components either, that will also break the whole thing.

Comment: _"What can i do to make it intented as i meant to be?"_ - might be that you can't do anything; neither `max-height` nor `height` _apply_ to column groups. Perhaps ypu can replace the actual table with a CSS grid to achieve a similar display ...

Comment: yes, i might use grid system. Which one do you recommend to use for better performance? Native css or bootstrap grid? i guess it's native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables don't allow for setting max-heights since they have `display:table`

You could make a container div around the table, give it a `max-height` and `overflow` value, and remove `display:block;` from the `thead` and `tbody-responsive`, as I've done below.
To make the headers stay in place during scroll, you can make them sticky by adding `position:sticky;` and `top:0;` to them, as I've shown below.

```css
.item-list .item-detail{
    margin: 0 0 2px 4px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

.table > :not(caption) > * > * {
    padding: 0.3rem 0.3rem !important;
    background-color: var(--vz-table-bg);
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9999px var(--vz-table-accent-bg);
}
.color-display{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
.text-center {
    text-align: center !important;
}


.tbody-responsive{
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
thead{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.container{
    max-height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll; 
}
body{
    width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="item-list py-4">
  <div class="item-header">

  </div>
  <div class="item-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="container">
        <table class="table">
          <thead class="">
            <th>
              <h4><b>DETAIL</b></h4>
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              <h4><b>STOCK (Client)</b></h4>
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              <h4><b>STOCK (XXX)</b></h4>
            </th>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="tbody-responsive w-100">

            <tr>
              <td class="item-detail"> Polo SE, Red <span class="color-display" style="background-color: red"></span>, XL</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
            </tr>
            
             <tr>
              <td class="item-detail"> Polo SE, Red <span class="color-display" style="background-color: red"></span>, XL</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
            </tr>
            
             <tr>
              <td class="item-detail"> Polo SE, Red <span class="color-display" style="background-color: red"></span>, XL</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
            </tr>
            
             <tr>
              <td class="item-detail"> Polo SE, Red <span class="color-display" style="background-color: red"></span>, XL</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
            </tr>
            
             <tr>
              <td class="item-detail"> Polo SE, Red <span class="color-display" style="background-color: red"></span>, XL</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
            </tr>
            
             <tr>
              <td class="item-detail"> Polo SE, Red <span class="color-display" style="background-color: red"></span>, XL</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
            </tr>
            
             <tr>
              <td class="item-detail"> Polo SE, Red <span class="color-display" style="background-color: red"></span>, XL</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
            </tr>
            
             <tr>
              <td class="item-detail"> Polo SE, Red <span class="color-display" style="background-color: red"></span>, XL</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
              <td class="item-detail text-center">1</td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man, your solution works fine. I just need to tweak somethings to better suite my code. Once again, thank you for your answe.